# Unexpected type inference with RxJava

Tags: java, generics, collections, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a common Transformer that simply filters a list using a given Predicate:

```
public class ListFilter<T> implements Observable.Transformer<List<T>, List<T>> {
    private final Predicate<T> predicate;

    private ListFilter(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    public static <T> Observable.Transformer<List<T>, List<T>> create(Predicate<T> predicate) {
        return new ListFilter<>(predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<List<T>> call(Observable<List<T>> listObservable) {
        return listObservable
                .flatMap(list -> Observable.from(list)
                        .filter(predicate::test)
                        .toList());
    }
}
```

Now I can filter a list of items with a minimum boilerplate, like this:

```
repository.observeItems() // returns Observable<List<SomeItem>>
        .compose(ListFilter.create(item -> /* some filter logic */)
```

But there's something I can't explain:

```
List<? extends Dummy> list = SomeDummyFactory.create();
BehaviorSubject<List<? extends Dummy>> subject = BehaviorSubject.create(list);

// #1 -> ok
BehaviorSubject.create(list)
    .compose(ListFilter.create(item -> /* `item` is `Dummy` */)
    ...

// #2 -> error
subject
    .compose(ListFilter.create(item -> /* `item` is `Object` */)) 
    ...

// #3 -> ok
subject
    .map(any -> any) // do nothing
    .compose(ListFilter.create(item -> /* `item` is `Dummy` */)) 
    ...
```

The only difference I can see between #2 and #3 is the expected wildcards of a `Transformer<T, R>`:

- _#2: `Transformer<? super List<? extends Dummy>, ? extends R>`
- _#3: `Transformer<? super List<capture of ? extends Dummy>, ? extends List<capture of ? extends Dummy>`

So there're a few questions:

1. Why `Object` is the type of an `item` in the 2nd case (and not `Dummy`)?
2. Why can't Java infer the return type of a Transformer in the 2nd case?
3. How does `map` operator help with it?
4. Why does the 1st case work fine?

Answer (score 0):

It is because compiler can't re-capture wildcard type.

In your first case, you can try to add explicit generic. Both `<Dummy>` and `<Object>` will lead error. The fact geneirc type is `(captrue#1 ?) extends Dummy` which is infered by the `create`'s generic return value.

In your second case, your `subject` generic type is `List<? extends Dummy>`. The `compose` must accept `Transformer<? super List<? extends Dummy>,? extends R>>`, so the `create` generic must be `? extends Dummy`(same as case 1). But in current compile context (current statement), the wildcard type is not captured. Compiler can't infer the generic type, it simply use `Object`, so error happens.

In your third case, the `map` capture the wildcard type back. You can try any method with a generic `Observable<R>` return type, all of them will work. Such as `.flatMap(d -> Observable.just(d))`.

**But note, your case 3 is just a workaround. The recommanded solution is let your `ListFilter`'s generic more flexible.**

You should define it as `ObservableTransformer<List<? extends T>, List<? extends T>>`

```
class ListFilter<T> implements ObservableTransformer<List<? extends T>, List<? extends T>> {

  public static <T> ListFilter<T> create(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return new ListFilter<>(predicate);
  }

  private final Predicate<T> predicate;

  private ListFilter(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    this.predicate = predicate;
  }

  @Override
  public ObservableSource<List<? extends T>> apply(Observable<List<? extends T>> upstream) {
    return upstream
        .flatMapSingle(list -> Observable.fromIterable(list)
            .filter(predicate::test)
            .toList());
  }
}
```